# Do you HAVE to prestige?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I just hit level 50 in Black Ops.

I now see the experience bar showing my next level is 1.

Does that mean I will have to prestige?  I thought it was optional (because there is a menu option for it on my player card).

Comment: it *is* optional. It's a matter of ePrestige whether you prestige or not. I'd suggest try it once and see if you like your new clothes. If they don't match, there are another 50 levels of excitement ahead of you..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have too, but there's a few minor advantages to prestiging: You get access to additional player card backdrops, more custom class slots, a prestige only leader board and prestige specific playlists.

The main downside is you have to earn all of your unlocks over again. The only thing you get to keep is your player card. Not even your CoD bucks carry over.

My advice? If you got to level 50 in less than a month, and intend to play the game for a few more months, prestige only once. There's plenty to do after you hit 50. I still have a bunch of challenges left to complete (although I did prestige once already and I'm at 50 again now).

I don't know this for sure, but if the matchmaking algorithm considers the prestige count and you're a mediocre player that got his level through playing a lot, rather than skill, you may actually end up playing with people who are significantly better than you when you do prestige, if the assumption is true that hardcore players who genuinely are better than you are more likely to prestige. Yeah, there's a few assumptions here.

Comment: You forgot to mention a prestige unlock which is the sole motivation to prestige for a lot of people (including myself): Golden Gun. At level 14th prestige, you unlock golden camo for your weapons. Who doesn't want to use a Golden AK?

Answer (score 8):

I believe you don't ***have*** to prestige, but level 50 is the maximum in Black Ops.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to, but you get a nifty icon, more custom class slots and access to a few more player cards. At later prestige levels you get alternate face paints and even golden gun camo at Prestige 15.

**IMPORTANT TO KNOW: The ONLY things you get to carry over to the next prestige level are the modifications to your player card. If you're going to Prestige I highly recommend spending every bit of your COD bucks on player card alterations, because you lose all of your COD bucks when you Prestige.**

Answer (score 1):

It's your choice. When you get prestige, you can access many things like the golden fun (at 14 prestige), new custom items and also a player card. Don't worry about your level because at your prestige they should see your emblem not don't care about the noobs.

The level doesn't count because even though you are at level 1 or more, and you are versing a level 50 opponent and using a weapon like an mp5k, you could still win. So don't worry!

For me, I think is better to get prestige because you are stronger when you face with people of your level and you could win 1 rank. Then you will gain more respect from them!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to. The challenge is there. You may get as many XP/CoD Points you want, though, it will make your decision to move on harder. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think he is asking whether or not hanging around level 50 for more than a little while is lame or not. In my opinion, it is, although as soon as I went Prestige, I was missing the perks and Commando like crazy and could not wait to get it back, so it's your own personal preference. You have to ask yourself, do you want to have 5 stars or a good-looking something, or would you rather have an eagle claw?

Answer (score 0):

There is no real reason to NOT prestige. If you stay at level 50, you may not be properly matched up against people of a similar level, if you manage to complete loads of challenges, it means nothing as XP is just wasted.

I debated prestiging the second time, but decided that there would be no point in playing on if I was staying at level 50.

Also remember that when you prestige, all your challenges are reset, apart from the 'Lifetime' ones. So if you are close to completing one of those, it may be worth prestiging and then completing that to jump you up a few levels.

Comment: Black Ops player matching isn't skill-based. (That said, there *is* the Prestige lobby that becomes available once you prestige.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no point to prestige. Just get your pro percs and have fun using them. The question is, if you don't prestige, will you still get to face golden gun players in team deathmatch? I have played against golden gun players in demolition and stuff, but i don't think i've encountered a golden gun player in team deathmatch.

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! Please ask follow-up questions by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button, not by posting them as answers.

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! Your answer here is a bit insubstantial as to *why* there is no requirement for prestige, so I'd recommend adding that kind of information. As noted by mmyers, please also do not post questions as answers - it would be wise to subtract that aspect of your post here. Please review our [FAQ] if you have not yet done so.